# Issue with Twitterizer API (Github) version 2.4.2

Tags: json, twitter, nuget-package, twitterizer

I am using twitter login & offline tweet post by saving Access-token, AccessTokenSecret using Github Twitterizer version 2.4.2.

DLLs used:

1.)Twitterizer version 2.4.2

2.)Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5.5

Result :
We are getting below result.

Access-level : Twitterizer.AccessLevel.Unavailable
Content : ""
Result : Unauthorized

RequestUrl : http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json

We are unable to get JSON data while sending details like Access-token, AccessTokenSecret, Consumer-key, Consumer-secret.
We have also installed PCA-3G2.pem and PCA-3G3.pem certificates on our SSL/TLS server, but we are still facing this issue. Kindly help to get it resolved. (find below the code snippet, I've used in my web-application)

Code :

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens()
  {
     Access-token = XXX-XXX,
     AccessTokenSecret =XXX-XXX,
     ConsumerKey = XXX-XXX,
     ConsumerSecret = XXX-XXX
  };
        TwitterResponse<TwitterUser> twitterResponse = TwitterAccount.VerifyCredentials(tokens);
        if (twitterResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = string.Format("Success! Verified as {0}", twitterResponse.ResponseObject.ScreenName);
            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> twitterRes = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Some 2", null);
            ResultLabel.CssClass = "ResultLabelSuccess";

            if (twitterRes.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text += string.Format(". Update Status Success!! Updated text {0}", twitterRes.ResponseObject.Text);
                ResultLabel.CssClass = "ResultLabelSuccess";
            }
            else
            {
                ResultLabel.Text += string.Format(". Update Status Failed! {0}", twitterRes.ErrorMessage);
                ResultLabel.CssClass = "ResultLabelFailed";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = string.Format("Failed! \"{0}\"", twitterResponse.ErrorMessage ?? "Not Authorized.");
            ResultLabel.CssClass = "ResultLabelFailed";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent 2 weeks for research on this issue and finally find the solution. According to Twitter, you need to use HTTPS connection instead of HTTP from 14th Jan 2014. If you are using Twitterizer version 2.4.2, please modify the Twitterizer24Classes file, and change "http://api.twitter.com/1/" to "".

Comment: David, could you please tell me where is the class you mention to change?